# Could not create Profile: TNS-04414: File error

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm installing `Oracle Database 12c Release 2 Installer`, and it jumps error message

> [INS 20802] Oracle Net Configuration Assistant Failed.

and the log flie error message is

```
INFO:     Parameter "maskpasswords" = false
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "maskpasswords" = false
INFO: Read: Done parsing command line arguments.
INFO: Done parsing command line arguments.
WARNING: Skipping line: Done parsing command line arguments.
INFO: Read: Oracle Net Services Configuration:
INFO: Oracle Net Services Configuration:
WARNING: Skipping line: Oracle Net Services Configuration:
INFO: Read: ProfileException: Could not create Profile: TNS-04414: File error
INFO: ProfileException: Could not create Profile: TNS-04414: File error
WARNING: Skipping line: ProfileException: Could not create Profile: TNS-04414: File error
INFO: Read: Error: null
INFO: Error: null
WARNING: Skipping line: Error: null
INFO: Read: Check the trace file for details: E:\app\test2\cfgtoollogs\netca\trace_OraDB12Home1-2006184ŕň2754.log
INFO: Check the trace file for details: E:\app\test2\cfgtoollogs\netca\trace_OraDB12Home1-2006184ŕň2754.log
WARNING: Skipping line: Check the trace file for details: E:\app\test2\cfgtoollogs\netca\trace_OraDB12Home1-2006184ŕň2754.log
INFO: Read: Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1
INFO: Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1
WARNING: Skipping line: Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Net Configuration Assistant
INFO: Oracle Net Configuration Assistant failed.
INFO: Oracle Net Configuration Assistant failed.
INFO: ConfigClient.executeSelectedToolsInAggregate action performed
INFO: Exiting ConfigClient.executeSelectedToolsInAggregate method
INFO: 
 The Runconfig command constructed is E:\app\test2\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\oui\bin\runConfig.bat ORACLE_HOME=E:\app\test2\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1 MODE=perform ACTION=configure RERUN=false %*
INFO: Since the option is to overwrite the existing E:\app\test2\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\cfgtoollogs\configToolFailedCommands file, backing it up
INFO: The backed up file name is E:\app\test2\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\cfgtoollogs\configToolFailedCommands.bak.5
INFO: Adding ExitStatus SUCCESS_MINUS_RECTOOL to the exit status set
INFO: ConfigClient.saveSession method called
INFO: Calling event ConfigSessionEnding
INFO: ConfigClient.endSession method called
INFO: Completed Configuration
```

How to solve this error and let install going forward?

Screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT**

I then try to use DBCA to create, but unfortunately first time it hang stuck at 44%, 2/3/4 time it stuck at 59% ...

This is a related [article](https://smarttechways.com/2019/08/19/dbca-got-stuck-at-59-at-second-database-in-oracle/) but not work ... `@Oracle Corporation` help me with your product please...

Comment: Your _installation_ completed just fine.  It was the follow-on creation of a database that failed. And unfortunately, this often happens when one chooses to create a database as part of the installation.  I'd just come back with the 'dbca' utility to create the database.

Comment: I haved try to use DBCA to create, but unfortunately first time it hang stuck at 44%, 2/3/4 time it stuck at 59%  ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you apply for this :

**TNS-04414 While Configuring A Listener Using NetCA Or Net Configuration Assistant (Doc ID 467391.1)**

Is it a listener.ora file is already present in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory ?.  If so, try to review the syntax of it. You are trying to add a new listener using Oracle Net Configuration Assistant (NETCA).

Check listener.ora file for missing parenthesis:

LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)  <--missing closing parenthesis
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))
 )

1. Correct the syntax error in the listener.ora. The corrected listener.ora entry would appear as -

   LISTENER =
    (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )

or

2. Rename the present listener.ora file and create a new file using NETCA.

Note - Renaming the present lisetner.ora file and creating a new one with NETCA will remove all the old listener configurations.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, I give it a try but I'm new to Oracle so not sure it just don't work. Then I close the DB install program, and try to  use DBCA to create, but unfortunately first time it hang stuck at 44%, 2/3/4 time it stuck at 59% ...

Comment: Hi, I always considered that installing Oracle in Windows is a nightmare! Perhaps it is better first to clean up the register before to attempt a second instalation. Can you tell me which Windows version you have ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the content of this file ?

E:\app\test2\cfgtoollogs\netca\trace_OraDB12Home1-2006184ŕň2754.log

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Yang09701194/9f3ff13049132d8d514e3c8dc0e5312f

Comment: Since the whole file of the whole install progress is large, so I first clear all content, and click retry, and log only the retry action

Comment: Thank you, if you need the complete log during whole install, I can reinistall again and get the log

Comment: Thank you for the file. It does not say anything relevant. Are you installing the DB software only, or you are creating the database as well

Comment: I saw the TNS 1444 error in your file.  Read my answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: You also can skip the step and do it afterwards , either manually or using NETCA

Comment: did you check what I told you ? If you skip the step I can show you how to create the listener and all network files manually